# Multiline text is displayed as a single line in firefox using knockoutjs bindings

Tags: javascript, firefox, knockout.js

I've just ran into a pretty strange behaviour of multiline text in firefox using knockoutjs bindings.
Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NznVZ/.

We have a textarea and span with value/text binding to the same observable.
Currently, Chrome and IE do display a multiline text in span element, but firefox doesn't (it just concatenates several lines into 1).

Can someone explain what is/where is the problem?
Maybe someone had already run into this issue and has a solution?

Thanks in advance

P.S. Firefox 12, IE 9, Chrome 18

Comment: I tested with ff12 and no problem at all.

Comment: @xandy have you tried putting line breaks? If you do, in FF they're concatenated in the span, but other browser insert proper BRs

Comment: I tried putting \n in the javascript, works. And I tried pressing Enter in textbox, works.

Comment: @xandy, that's pretty weird. I could repro this on my FF 12 without a problem

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Setting the `white-space: pre-wrap` style on the span will make it work: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/NznVZ/12/

Here's a little background. IE and Chrome will convert the newlines in the string to `<br>` elements in the HTML when the text is set using `innerText`, which is what Knockout uses. Firefox doesn't have `innerText` so Knockout uses `textContent`, which doesn't do any conversion of the string. (Interestingly, Chrome matches Firefox when you use the `white-space: pre-wrap` style.)

IE:

```
<span>First line.<br>Second Line.<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Third line preceded with 5 space characters.</span>
```

Chrome (without white-space style):

```
<span>First line.<br>Second Line.<br>     Third line preceded with 5 space characters.</span>
```

Firefox and Chrome (with white-space style):

```
<span>First line.
Second Line.
     Third line preceded with 5 space characters.</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want a javascript solution: http://jsfiddle.net/9KAQX/

The only advantage here is that "\n" characters are not present in the span.

Comment: Works fine unless your text contains special HTML characters, like less-than or greater-than symbol.  Try typing 3 < 6, for example :)